# Abrir Servidor Local PHP a partir de aplicação VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Queria saber se é possível abrir um servidor local PHP a partir de uma aplicação VB.NET, pode ser um servidor bem básico, como o VertrigoServ, por que é mesmo só para executar alguns códigos basicões mesmo através da aplicação.

Comment: Você está usando Apache, IIS ou NGINX para rodar o PHP em sua máquina? Ou não decidiu isto ainda?

Comment: Estou usando Apache

Comment: você quer fazer um software que inicia o servidor apache ou você quer fazer uma requisição HTTP?

Comment: Quero iniciar o servidor apache a partir da minha aplicação

Comment: Só mais uma duvida o seu Apache está usando FastCGI ou ApacheHandler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se entendi, você tem um servidor WAMP instalado na sua maquina (suponho que seja Apache, Mysql e PHP)

> Vou presumir que o seu Apache esteja usando ApacheHandler ao invés de FastCGI no "Server API "

Em qualquer método de chamada pelo Windows (por exemplo CMD), você deve chamar o programa e passar os argumentos se necessário.

Para chamar qualquer programa no .NET você pode usar o [`ProcessStartInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Passos a seguir:

1. Localize o programa `httpd.exe` (deve estar em uma pasta como `C:\Apache\Apache2.4\bin\httpd.exe`)
2. Se estiver a usar Mysql, localize o `mysqld.exe`, deve ser algo como `C:\mysql\mysql5.2\bin\mysqld.exe`
3. E localizar o `my.ini` do Mysql (se realmente for usar mysql nos seus scripts), o caminho deve ser algo como `C:\mysql\mysql5.2\my.ini`

Agora que temos os caminhos, devemos criar um método para cada processo (pode até reaproveitar o mesmo metodo, mas isto é outra história):

Supondo que o caminho do apache seja algo como `C:\Apache\Apache2.4\bin\httpd.exe`, devemos executar um comando tipo este (para rodar ele como serviço, não é necessariamente obrigatório):

```
"C:\Apache\Apache2.4\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

Para usar com `ProcessStartInfo`:

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
startInfo.FileName = "C:\Apache\Apache2.4\bin\httpd.exe"
startInfo.Arguments = "-k runservice"

' Para ocultar a janela do processo
p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

Process.Start(startInfo)
```

Para chamar o Mysql (se necessário para os seus scripts) você deve usar algo como:

```
C:\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=C:\mysql\my.ini --console
```

O método deve ser algo como:

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
startInfo.FileName = "C:\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe"
startInfo.Arguments = "--defaults-file=C:\mysql\my.ini --console"

' Para ocultar a janela do processo
p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

Process.Start(startInfo)
```